# OkHttp request via Proxy with Authentcation fails

Tags: android, proxy, okhttp

Similar question was at GitHub: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2900

I'm trying to make a request using code:

```
final Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("proxyhost", 8001));
final Response response = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .proxy(proxy)
        .proxyAuthenticator(new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            public Request authenticate(Route route, Response response) throws IOException {
                String credential = Credentials.basic("proxyuser", "proxypass");
                return response.request().newBuilder()
                        .header("Proxy-Authorization", credential)
                        .build();                        
            }
        })
        .build()
        .newCall(new Request.Builder()
                .get()
                .url("https://www.google.com/")
                .build())
        .execute();
```

But I get the error: `407 Proxy Authentication Required`

Btw, when I set up proxy on my PC, open Chrome and go to google, a window pops up where I should enter login and password. And if I click cancel - the same page appers with text

> 407 Proxy Authentication Required. Access to requested resource
>   disallowed by administrator or you need valid username/password to use
>   this resource

So my question is how to use proxy with OkHttp? It would be useful to know other ways or libraries to work with the proxy

Comment: Looks like you've got it configured right. Can you confirm that the authenticator is getting called?

Comment: @JesseWilson yes, absolutely. Here in 'public Request authenticate(Route route, Response response)' response has code 407 and when code is executed it throws java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line

Comment: Gotcha. It's a parse error. Your proxy is returning something OkHttp can't handle. If you can diagnose, that'll help.

Answer (score -2):

Try to remove Basic from the net.properties in jre/lib folder

```
jdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=Basic
```

needs to be

```
jdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=
```